# Data clustering, growing margine, seasonality, forecast in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics

I want to do some data analysis using Excel and this tasks I need to answer.
*data clustering
*margine
*seasonality/forecast

Can somebody give me an input maybe?

I am not coming from financial/statistical/analytical field, and these things are more less new to time, but I would like to learn how to do this in Excel.

Here is my data set, where time axis is non consecutive (for forecast prediction for instance).

[image]